# Convert LocalPoints to Lat/Long in GMap

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, gmap.net

I'm using GMap.Net.WindowsForms 1.7 for integrating maps into my application.

I'm at the point where, I've uploaded multiple Routes to the map interface and I need to return that data from the GMapControl and export it into a KML document.

The problem I'm facing is returning the points from the Route list to stick into the KML.

Originally when you add the Lat Long data into the route, its stored as PointLatLng.  As soon as the map changes zoom its converted to 'LocalPoints' which don't really mean much to me.  I was hoping for Lat Long numbers.
Is there a way to convert this data to Lat Longs?

```
GPoint point = FlightpathOverlay.Routes[0].LocalPoints[0];
point.X =  1476
point.Y = -1328
```

Comment: Does the zoom work correctly? The reason I'm asking is that the coordinates should be preserved, when the map is being zoomed, they should be available throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GMapRoute` inherits from `MapRoute` which holds references to the coordinates in a `public List<PointLatLng> Points`, you can retrieve the route's coordinates from there.

Comment: Thanks rdoubleui!  I have no idea how I missed this as I was using it when exporting polygon overlays.  Complete failure on behalf, thanks for pointing out the obvious to me!